# Hidden Relic or Easter Egg

Tags: innerspace

**[EDIT]** This relic is exclusive to the Kickstarter backers :

https://twitter.com/GodJammit/status/1091056708900843521
https://twitter.com/GodJammit/status/1091060714326904832

Anyway, since there's no video about it... maybe some backer could show us this relic on YouTube, some day ? ^^;

---

It seems that I'm missing a relic, as shown in the title screen with the grayed icon :

[image: title screen relics]
[image: title screen relics detailed]

However, the in-game relics counters let's think that we have found everything :

[image: relics counters]

Finally, I have found a three-parts relic named "Fundamental Scraps" in the game files :

[image: fundamental scraps completed]
[image: fundamental scraps signatures]

So this could be an hidden easter egg.

Comment: I can do a little more research later, but the 'founders' phrasing makes me think that it may be a Kickstarter reward. Can't remember off the top of my head if I got anything extra